# How can I concatenate all values in descending order that have the same primary key in HIVE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive, hiveql

I am using HIVE and I have a table like this:

| S.no | ID | applicant_num | f_name | l_name | Primary Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 202201A1 | akhil | yadav | 123~&~akhil~&~yadav |
| 2 | 123 | 202202A2 | akhil | yadav | 123~&~akhil~&~yadav |
| 3 | 123 | 202203A2 | akhil | yadav | 123~&~akhil~&~yadav |
| 4 | 987 | 202201B8 | ankit | yadav | 987~&~ankit~&~yadav |
| 5 | 987 | 202203B19 | ankit | yadav | 987~&~ankit~&~yadav |
| 6 | 987 | 202208B34 | ankit | yadav | 987~&~ankit~&~yadav |

I want to concatenate all the applicant_num for same primary_key into a string such that they maintain their descending order (Last application should come first).

Here is what I tried:

```
select 
    concat_ws('~', collect_set(applicant_num)), primary_key 
from 
    (select * 
     from table 
     order by applicant_num desc) 
group by 
    primary_key
```

Using this query I am getting a result like this:

| applicant_num | Primary Key |
| --- | --- |
| 202203A2~202201A1~202202A2 | 123~&~akhil~&~yadav |
| 202203B19~202208B34~202201B8 | 987~&~ankit~&~yadav |

whereas what I want is

| applicant_num | Primary Key |
| --- | --- |
| 202203A2~202202A2~202201A1 | 123~&~akhil~&~yadav |
| 202208B34~202203B19~202201B8 | 987~&~ankit~&~yadav |

The concatenation is not maintaining the descending order.

I tried

```
select 
    concat_ws('~', sort_array(collect_set(applicant_num))), primary_key 
from 
    (select * 
     from table 
     order by applicant_num desc) 
group by 
    primary_key
```

But `sort_array` returns array in ascending order and it cannot be sorted in descending.

Is there any to concatenate all applicant_num in one string for a primary key while maintaining the descending order of applicant_num?

Answer (score 1):

PySpark API of [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort) always sorting in ascending order (shame).

Luckily, Spark SQL API of [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort) does support it (sort of). So despite the unnecessary lengthy expression, this is what you're looking for

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, '1x'),
    (1, '1a'),
    (1, '1b'),
    (2, '2a'),
    (2, '2b'),
    (2, '2c'),
], ['id', 'col'])

(df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(
        F.concat_ws('~', F.expr('array_sort(collect_list(col), (left, right) -> case when left < right then 1 when left > right then -1 else 0 end)')).alias('col')
    )
    .show()
)

+---+--------+
| id|     col|
+---+--------+
|  1|1x~1b~1a|
|  2|2c~2b~2a|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort_array` can also be sorted in `descending` order, Please refer to [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#sort_array)

```
select 
    concat_ws('~', sort_array(collect_set(applicant_num), false)), primary_key 
from 
    (select * 
     from table 
     order by applicant_num desc) 
group by primary_key
```

Comment: It says Arguments length mismatch ‘false’ : sortarray requires 1 argument(s), got 2. In using hive, not spark. Hiveql might not have this functionality to pass true false

Comment: sorry, my bad. I haven't used hql for a long time, so I'm rusty.